# Cannot catch SQL Server alter table error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

It is a really simple code, but it cannot catch the error.

Or how to catch the error?

Thanks.

```
BEGIN TRY
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table_name] 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY ([id]);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Primary Key already exists. '
END CATCH
```

Comment: You might find this useful:  http://www.sqlusa.com/articles2008/trycatch/.

Comment: Maybe you can verify if already exists...  IF NOT EXITS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY' ....blah

Comment: IF NOT exists (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table_name] ADD PRIMARY KEY ([id]);

Comment: Thanks, it also works.

Comment: Great "Most languages have existing control structures designed to solve your problems without the use of exceptions"  Don't fall into antipatterns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Errors that occur as a result of batch recompilation after deferred name resolution cannot be caught at the same level the error occurs.  One work-around is to wrap the DDL in dynamic SQL:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table_name] ADD PRIMARY KEY ([id]);');
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1779
    BEGIN
        --handle expected errors
        PRINT 'Primary Key already exists. ';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --raise other unexpected errors
        THROW;
    END;
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is absolutely good, but there is another method to catch error when you use DDL, use stored procedure inside of `TRY` block.
Based on MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#errors-unaffected-by-a-trycatch-construct).

If you don't want to keep your stored procedure, you can easily drop it on the end of the try.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.sp_my_proc
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_my_proc
AS
    --Your original code here:
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_table_name] 
    ADD PRIMARY KEY ([id]);
GO

BEGIN TRY  
    EXECUTE dbo.sp_my_proc 
    --Optional, if you don't want to keep sp
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.sp_my_proc  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    --Catch your error here
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;
```

So there is two way to handle this.